# Exception has occurred: OSError -> OSError: No such file or directory

Tags: python, nlp

```py
from nltk.corpus import CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
reader = (r'/[볼륨명]/Data/NLPCookBook/Reviews/txt_sentoken',r'*\.txt', cat_pattern=r'(\w+/*')
Print(reader.categories())
print(reader.fileids())
```

I tried to learner natural language processing with python by myself.So I followed exactly what the book said and I got the error like this.

```
Exception has occurred: OSError
No such file or directory: 'C:\\[볼륨명]\\Data\\NLPCookBook\\Reviews\\txt_sentoken'
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\python study\.vscode\external_corpus.py", line 2, in <module>
    reader = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader(r'/[볼륨명]/Data/NLPCookBook/Reviews/txt_sentoken',r'*\.txt', cat_pattern=r'(\w+/*')
```

The book says that I am suppose to get

```py
['neg', 'pos']
[neg/cv00_tok-9611.txt, ~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

`Exception has occurred: OSError No such file or directory`
It just means that the file you are looking for doesnt exist in the path you have specified, try changing the file path.

Comment: I saved the file on Desktop folder. How can I specify the path to it?

Comment: Check this website out on how to get the path.
https://www.howtogeek.com/670447/how-to-copy-the-full-path-of-a-file-on-windows-10/
hope it helps :)